# Extra space before labeled theorem body with thmbox or thmtools+thmbox

Tags: spacing, theorems, ntheorem, thmtools

Package `thmbox` seems to add an extra space at the beginning of the body of the labeled theorems.  See example below.  Package `thmtools` with the `thmbox` option does the same.  Latex original, package `amsthm` and package `ntheorem` do not add the extra space.  I can solve the problem that occurs with `thmbox` by placing a `%` just after the label.  However, I do not want to do that because I should edit each already written theorem.  Problem *is* solved by including `\ignorespaces` in option `bodystyle` of `thmbox`.  However, then the body is indented.  If `bodystyle` is defined using `\noindent\ignorespaces` then the body is not indented, but the extra space shows up again.

```
\documentclass{report}

% ----- no extra space

%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

%\usepackage{ntheorem}
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

% ----- extra space

\usepackage{thmbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

%\usepackage{thmtools}
%\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{L1}
With label.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
Without label.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}     \label{L2}%
     With label, but solved, even having space characters here and there.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So ... what exactly is your question? Please advise.

Comment: The question is how do I solve the problem with package `thmbox` or package `thmtools` with option `thmbox`, without editing each already written labeled theorem.

Comment: It is not obvious, but there is an extra space added at the beginning of the line when there is a `\label{}` unless one uses `\label{}%` (trailing `%` added).  Interestingly, even [the `thmbox` documentation](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/thmbox) shows the use as `\label{}%`.

Comment: There also seems to be a different spacing problem when `amsthm` is used, but not with `ntheorem`.  With `amsthm`, there appears to be an additional space before the `3` in `Theorem 3`.

Comment: You are right.  This extra space seems to be added not because of the label or space characters, but because of the long text within the body.  That is, in order to obtain evenly spaced "words".  With a shorter body no extra space appears before the 3.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `\label` at the end:

```
\begin{theorem}
With label.\label{L1}
\end{theorem}
```

It's a bug in `thmbox` way of doing its work.