# Space generated by theorem labels (XeTeX)

Tags: spacing, theorems

With the `thmtools` package, combining `\begin{foo}[name=bar,label=x]` with the line `\newtheorem{foo}{Foo}` in the preamble typesets to Foo xxx (bar), where xxx is a number. After the (bar) there is an extra space which is about 6pt. To remove it completely, as I have seen at [Extra space before labeled theorem body with thmbox or thmtools+thmbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40679/extra-space-before-labeled-theorem-body-with-thmbox-or-thmtoolsthmbox), it is sufficient to add % after the `label=x]` part. The point is, if I add any number of `\,`s after it, they get completely ignored, whereas `\hspaces`, `\quad`s and `\qquad`s don't. Try typesetting:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\newtheorem{foo}{Foo}

\begin{document}
\begin{foo}[name=bar,label=x]\hspace{5cm}
With the space.
\end{foo}
\begin{foo}[name=bar2,label=x2]
Without the space.
\end{foo}
\begin{foo}[name=bar3,label=x3]\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
With 8 \verb"\,"s.
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```

On my computer, the `\,`s don't produce any space, whereas the `\hspace` does. Why does that happen?

Adding % after the label seems not to eliminate the space. Since this has generated a couple of overful \hboxes, I'd like to know how I can remove it.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\newtheorem{foo}{Foo}

\begin{document}
\begin{foo}[name=bar,label=x]%
With the \verb"%".
\end{foo}
\begin{foo}[name=bar2,label=x2]
Without the \verb"%".
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```

[image: The code above typesetted]

Comment: As David explains, the command `\,` is a bit dangerous. On the other hand a string of `\,` is surely wrong.

Comment: On the edited additional question,  I'm not sure why you'd expect a `%` there to have an effect. White space never affects the start of a paragraph or list item.

Comment: A theorem is a list item, and the space between `(bar)` and `With` is `\labelsep` so adding `\setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}` before `\begin{foo}` suppresses it.

Comment: The reason was that I thought, since it has that effect in `\label{}%`, as stated in the link I put in the question, by extension, it should do the same if placed there. Obviously that was wrong thinking :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\,` do generate space (as you can see in your image) but it is *vertical* space:

```
...\kern 1.70374
...\kern 1.70374
...\kern 1.70374
...\kern 1.70374
...\kern 1.70374
...\kern 1.70374
...\kern 1.70374
...\kern 1.70374
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 2.0
...\hbox(7.5+2.5)x345.0, glue set 225.66599fil
....\hbox(7.5+2.5)x67.92326
.....\glue 0.0
.....\glue 0.0
.....\glue -5.0
.....\hbox(7.5+2.5)x67.92326
......\glue 5.0
......\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 F
......\kern-0.95833
......\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 o
......\kern0.31944
......\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 o
......\glue 3.83331 plus 1.91666 minus 1.27777
......\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 3
```

`\hspace` generates a `\hskip` but `\,` if not in math mode generates a kern which doesn't automatically start a paragraph, so in vertical mode (as here) it adds vertical space. probably it ought to have been defined with `\leavevmode`

Comment: Yes, it ought to. ;-)

Comment: Has anyone noticed my last edit, which added an issue to the question? No because it's been a while and no-one has answered :).

Comment: @MickG It's best to ask new questions rather than edit old ones, really.